# Firebase Cloud Messaging - how to add sound to APN

Tags: firebase, audio, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

When sending an APN to an iOS device using `HTTP v1 API`, the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html) states that if `apns-priority` is set to `10`, then

```
Notifications with this priority must trigger an alert, sound, or badge on the target device
```

The [documentation at Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#ApnsConfig) seems to suggest adding to apns JSON object:

I am only successful when setting the priority **only** with the following in the JSON POST:

```
"apns": {
            "headers": {
                "apns-priority": "10"
            }
        },
```

When I POST the following as documentation suggests:

```
...
"apns": {
            "headers": {
                "apns-priority": "10"
            },
            "payload": {
                "sound": "default"
            }
        },
...
```

a `400 - Bad Request` returns back from FCM server.  If I exclude the `payload` json section, the POST works.

Also tried the following:

```
...
"apns": {
            "headers": {
                "apns-priority": "10"
            },
            "sound": "default"
...
```

still get a 400 - Bad Request

> How do I set sound on a the APN within the SDK API JSON POST?  A default sound is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sound object needs to be part of an `aps` object:

```
...
"apns": {
   "headers": {
       "apns-priority": "10"
    },
    "payload": {
        "aps": {
            "sound": "default"
        }
    }
 },
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your JSON, it appears you are using the HTTP v1 API.

The "apns" specific dictionary is described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#ApnsConfig).

For example, in order to play the default sound:

```
...
"apns": {
  "headers": {
    "apns-priority":"10"
  },
  "payload": {
    "sound":"default"
  },
},
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the link - but please see my post edit regarding your suggestion.